# Angular Nativescript RadListView not updating when push from another page

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have `RadListView` which gets data from `http` request. :

```
<RadListView #listView  separatorColor="transparent"
        pullToRefresh="true" (pullToRefreshInitiated)="refreshFavorites($event);" *ngIf="filteredItems && filteredItems.length; else noItems" row="2"
            [items]="filteredItems" marginTop="-100" (touch)="dismissKeyboard($event)">
    <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout columns="10,*,10">
            <GridLayout *ngIf="item" (tap)="goToInner(item)" [nsRouterLink]="['../favorite', item.ean]" pageTransition="slide"  shadow='6' cornerRadius='5' col="1" columns="*,auto" class="p-8 m-b-8 m-x-8" borderRadius="8"
            backgroundColor="white">
                <GridLayout class="favorite-card" col="0" columns="150,*,auto" rows="auto,auto,auto">
                    <Image col="0" rowSpan="3" class="thumbnail m-r-12" stretch="aspectFit" *ngIf="item.images"
                        [src]="item.images.large.url"></Image>
                        <StackLayout col="1" row="1" verticalAlingment="center">
                                <Label  class="h3 title m-t-4" marginBottom="0" textWrap="true" maxLines="2" [text]="item.productTitle"></Label>
                                <Label class="h5 caption" [text]="item.manufacturer"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                </GridLayout>
                <StackLayout col="1" verticalAlignment="top" (tap)="removeFromFavorites(item, i)">
                        <Image horizontalAlignment="right" src="~/images/favorite-active.png" width="20" height="20"></Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </GridLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
</RadListView>
```

If I want to update RadListView in inner.component it to add an item to the "radListView":

```
filteredItems : ObservableArray<Observable> = new ObservableArray([]);
public update(item){
    this.filteredItems.push(item)
}
```

But if I add item from another component, the radListView is not updated:

```
providers: [InnerComponent],    
constructor(private inner: InnerComponent){}
addItem(item){
    this.inner.update(item)
}
```

What I am doing wrong and why it's not updating? Why is my RadListView not updating after I call function from another component, but is updated from it's own component? The items are both the same in both components.

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a create a service and use BehaviorSubject as shown in this [example](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc). It is not a common practice to inject component using [providers](https://angular.io/guide/providers).
In your service.ts

```
filteredItems;



public filteredItemsSubsSource = new BehaviorSubject(new ObservableArray<item>());
public filteredItemsSubs = this.filteredItemsSubsSource.asObservable();

addItem(item){
    this.filteredItems.push(item);
    this.filteredItemsSubsSource.next(filteredItems);
}
```

so in another component inject the service and subscribe

```
providers: [Service],    
constructor(private _service: Service){}

addItem(item){
    this._service.addItem(item);
}
```

also

```
this._service.filteredItemsSubs.subscribe(
            (filteredItems) => {
                this.filteredItems= filteredItems;

            }
        );
```